# Differences between MDSD & MDD

Tags: model, dsl, model-driven-development

I would like to know if there is any difference between:

1. Model-Driven Software Development (MDSD)
2. Model-Driven Development (MDD)

I always find these two terms in many articles and public literature, but no one highlights the differences.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. The put the creation of a model in the center of the development process and generate all or part of the source code from that model.

It is popular in areas where the model of the programming language does not offer enough expressiveness for a common problem, e.g. Statemachines in embedded software engineering.